# installed new development framework not available

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I would like to have .NET Framework 4.6.2 as Target Framework in Visual Studio 2015 enterprise.

I've installed .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack (English version and language pack)

It's not available among my frameworks yet.

[image]
What could the issue be?

**Edit:**
Installing .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack and Developer Pack don't work either

Comment: If you create a plain class library project, are they available? I.e. could it be an issue, specifically, with the SharePoint project template?

Comment: you're right Damien_The_Unbeliever . It's because of the Sharepoint template